# Selenium: How to wait for options in a select to be populated?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium for the first time and am overwhelmed by the options. I am using the IDE in Firefox.

When my page loads, it subsequently fetches values via an JSONP request, with which it populates options in a select.

How do I get Selenium to wait for a certain option in the select to be present before proceeding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be use

`waitForElementPresent` command. If possible let's me see your selenium IDE code.

Comment: But you can not use this with page factory...can you?

Answer (score 13):

I used **`waitForElementPresent` with a css target**.

Example: To wait for

```
<select id="myselect"></select>
```

to be populated with

```
<option value="123">One-two-three</option>
```

use

- Command: `waitForElementPresent`
- Target: `css=#myselect option[value=123]`
- Value: (leave it empty)

Answer (score 4):

I found handy something like:

```
wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions
        .presenceOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(By.id(<selectioNId>), By.tagName("option"))
)
```

Comment: this is perfect for my needing: I know that there is a select element, but I needed to understand if the value is present in the options before to retrieve the elements, avoiding try to find put a value which it wasn't present.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "WaitForSelectOption" command where your value can be direct label
like 
label=1-saving Account 
target will have the object id

Comment: Works great when you just want to wait until you get the option populated in the select element.

Answer (score 2):

I made the following function in C# that returns the select when is populated.

You have to pass a By to find the element and you a specific time to wait for it to be filled:

```
public static SelectElement FindSelectElementWhenPopulated(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int delayInSeconds)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delayInSeconds));
        return wait.Until<SelectElement>(drv => 
        {
            SelectElement element = new SelectElement(drv.FindElement(by));
            if (element.Options.Count >= 2)
            {
                return element;
            }

            return null;
        }
        );
    }
```

In my case I validate tha the select has more than 2 options, you can change the code so that it validates the quantity that fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

We had similar problem where the options within drop down was fetched from a third party service, which sometimes was a slower operation.

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(cssSelector("cssSelectorOfSelectBox")));    
waitUnitlSelectOptionsPopulated(select)
```

here is the definition for waitUnitlSelectOptionsPopulated

```
private void waitUntilSelectOptionsPopulated(final Select select) {
            new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                    .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
                        public boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                            return (select.getOptions().size() > 1);
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Note: A check of select.getOptions().size() >1 was needed in our case as we had one static option always displayed.

Comment: How do you get access to the Select classes ? is it from some other selenium Nuget package ?

Answer (score 1):

Using **java 8** `Awaitility`

```
Awaitility.await()
.atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.until(() -> select.getOptions().size() > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    # 10 is the maximum time to wait
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mySelectId option[value='valueofOptionYouExpectToBeLoaded']"))
    )
except TimeoutException:
    print("Time out")

#  Write your code
```

Comment: Can you explain why I should try this code? What's better about it than the existing answers, specifically? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me:

```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='NamE']/option[1]"));
  return element.getAttribute("text");
```