# Cant Select a value or enter value to loading dropdown

Tags: java, selenium

There are three dropdowns 
Pool,category,material

options in category dropdown loads when a pool is selected
options in material dropdown loads when a category is selected

can seem to select a value on category

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<select name="ctl00$body$txtCategory" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$body$txtCategory\',\'\')', 0)" id="body_txtCategory" class="form-control">
<option selected="selected" value="-1">-- Select Item --</option>
<option value="56">Poultry</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: How to wait for options in a select to be populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568081/selenium-how-to-wait-for-options-in-a-select-to-be-populated)

Comment: driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$body$txtCategory")).sendKeys("Poultry");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select values from drop down using select in selenium web driver. senkeys not working for dropdown.

First you need to identify the drop down using select.You can select/deselect drop down value by using this.

> **SelectByVisibleText()/deselectByVisibleText()** : selects/deselects an option by its displayed text
>
> **selectByValue()/ deselectByValue()** : selects/deselects an option by
>   the value of its "value" attribute
>
> **selectByIndex()/ deselectByIndex()** : selects/deselects an option by its index

```
Select drpCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("body_txtCategory")));
drpCountry.selectByVisibleText("Poultry");
```

Comment: @FindBy(id = "body_txtPool")@CacheLookup
 Select Pool;
 public void Pool(String SelectPool) {
  Pool.selectByValue(SelectPool);
 }   doesn't seem to work on this

Comment: @JohnCedrickBecherCing please update that in your question