# I want to click on an item based on the inner text inside a specific path

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I want to click on an item by its visible text inside a specific path 
[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHdLx.png) 
I want to click on these option tag by its value or the inner text based on its path as these values (date picker) are repeated in other sections

Comment: Please do not post screenshots; instead, include the code in your question.

Comment: You can refer this for precise solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55770300/cant-select-a-value-or-enter-value-to-loading-dropdown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a dropdown value in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement x=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='calendars-month-year']/option[1]"));

String y=x.getAttribute("innerText"); // =1288

if (y.equals("1288"){
    x.click();
    }
```

Or directly

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='calendars-month-year']/option[1]")).click(); //this will click on the first option
```

Comment: There's no reason to do this because it's a `SELECT` element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to select an option by its visible text value. You can use the following code to do the same:

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='calendars-month-year']")));
sel.selectByVisibleText("1289");
```

Comment: I have the same class 'calender-moth-year' repeated in other section of HTML (2 date picker ) so I want to click on a specific one

Comment: @MohammedEsa Then you need to create a unique locator to find the exact `SELECT` element that you want. We can't help you with that until you post the relevant HTML or preferably a link to the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `By.xpath("//option[contains(.,'1290')]")` or `By.xpath("//option[text() = '1290']")`

Comment: There's no reason to do this because it's a `SELECT` element.